# Cholesky decomposition for special structure matrix

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, matrix-decomposition, cholesky-decomposition

Suppose the matrix is of the form $\tilde{A} = aI -A^TA$, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $a>eig(A^TA)$. Assume that Cholesky decomposition is possible. Do we get a nice analytic expression or low cost computation for Cholesky decomposition of $\tilde{A}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A^TA = PDP^T$ be the eigen-decomposition for $A^TA$.  Notice then we can write:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\tilde{A} & = & aI - A^TA \\
& = & aI - PDP^T \\
& = & aPP^T - PDP^T \\
& = & P\left (aI - D\right )P^T \\
& = & P \sqrt{aI - D}\sqrt{aI-D}P^T.
\end{eqnarray*}

Let $H = \sqrt{aI-D}P^T$, therefore $\tilde{A} = H^TH$ is the Cholesky decomposition.